# toggle check box is not working in angular js , its only showing off always

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i want to show on and off based on scope variable. but its always showing off , incase of on or checked also.in the console window its showing checked, but in the toggle button its showing off

html

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled ng-checked="{{comp1status}}"
       data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="outline-success"
       data-offstyle="outline-danger"><br />
```

tried with

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled ng-model="comp2status" data-toggle="toggle"
       data-onstyle="outline-success" data-offstyle="outline-danger">
```

this also not worked

js

```
$scope.comp1status = response.data.ISCmpr1;
if ($scope.comp1status === "0") {
    $scope.comp1status = "checked";
}
else {
    $scope.comp1status = "unchecked";
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting to `'checked'` and `'unchecked'`, have you tried to set to `true` and `false` respectively? Based on the AngularJS docs, it is checking for the "truthiness" of the values in `ng-checked`. Non-empty strings are considered truthy in JS, so they both would show as checked. I tested that out using the `ng-checked="comp1status"` syntax and it works for me. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: i have set true and false , that also not working. ng-checked="{{comp2status}}"

Comment: Try to remove the curly braces and just do `ng-checked="comp2status"`

Comment: $scope.comp3status = "true";?.  <input type="checkbox" disabled ng-checked="comp3status"  data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="outline-success" data-offstyle="outline-danger">

Comment: You want the `true` and `false` values to not be strings but rather boolean values. Here is a stackblitz showing the working simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ng-checked

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is one-way binding, use `ng-checked` but don't use interpolation (`{{ }}`):

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled  ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶=̶"̶{̶{̶c̶o̶m̶p̶1̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶}̶}̶"̶
                                 ng-checked="comp1status" >
```

Use boolean values in the controller:

```
$scope.comp1status = response.data.ISCmpr1;
if ($scope.comp1status === "0") {
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶c̶o̶m̶p̶1̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶"̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶"̶;̶
    $scope.comp1status = true;
}
else {
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶c̶o̶m̶p̶1̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶"̶u̶n̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶e̶d̶"̶;̶
    $scope.comp1status = false;
}
```

The DEMO

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input type="checkbox" disabled ng-checked="check">Checkbox<br>

    <select ng-model="check">
       <option ng-value="" disabled>Select value</option>
       <option ng-value="false">unchecked</option>
       <option ng-value="true">checked</option>
    </select>
 </body>
```

Comment: but im looking for toogle button input type toggle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this code will help you

```js
class AppController {
  constructor($scope, $q) {
    this.deferred = $q.defer();
    $scope.comp1status = true;
    this.getComp2Status()
      .then(comp2status => {
        $scope.comp2status = comp2status;
      });
  }

  getComp2Status() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.deferred.resolve(true);
    }, 2000);
    return this.deferred.promise;
  }
}

AppController.$inject = ['$scope', '$q'];

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('appController', AppController);

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.app {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div ng-controller="appController" class="app">
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input ng-model="comp1status" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="comp1status">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="comp1status">Comp1 status</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input ng-model="comp2status" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="comp2status">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="comp2status">Comp2 status async</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use object to solve this issue and also use '==' instead of '===' if you are not sure about the data type that is returned.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="someObject.someProperty"> Check Me!

// Controller

$scope.comp1status = response.data.ISCmpr1;
if ($scope.comp1status == "0") {
  $scope.someObject.someProperty = false;
}
else {
  $scope.someObject.someProperty = true;
}
```

Comment: "use '==' instead of '==='" this is generally considered a bad practice

Comment: If we are not sure about the data type that is returned by the API, then it is acceptable. Using === is good only if the data is managed by data

Comment: It's best to determine the API response format instead of guessing at types. When JS does the `==` equality check it converts from one type to another and can lead to unknown bugs. For example, `true == 'true'` evaluates to `false`. In this case, if you didn't know if it was returning a boolean `true` or the string `'true'` and opted for this pattern, the code would just not work.